# How to Handle Auto Suggestion Dropdown with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, dropdown

I am trying to fullfill this form via a python script: https://reassurez-moi.fr/simulation-tarifaire-assurance-habitation?homeType=1

But unfortunately I don't know how to Handle Auto Suggestion Dropdown with Selenium in Python.

In fact, I want to select the first element of my dropdown list when I write a street name (In French: 'Adresse du bien').

Can you tell me how to make a python script that allows me to do this?

Thank you in advance.

The code below show what I have done so far but it does not allow me to choose one of the values from my Auto Suggestion drop-down list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
web1 = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
web1.get('https://reassurez-moi.fr/simulation-tarifaire-assurance-habitation?homeType=1')
#time.sleep(2)
topics_xpath = '//*[@id="home-comparator-base"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'
WebDriverWait(web1,2).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, topics_xpath)))
Rue_Adresse = "Rue de la Paix"
last = web1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home-comparator-base"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/input')
last.send_keys(Rue_Adresse)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this element

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[1]
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]
/html/body/div[5]/div[3]
```

[dropdown responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWuze.png)